# Using a global variable to prevent code executing repeatedly unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, electron, global

**TL;DR:** Is it bad practice to use a global variable to prevent code executing unnecessarily, and if so what are the alternatives?

I have an Electron application that reads a stream of real time data from another application and outputs some elements of it on screen.

There are two types of data received, real time (telemetry) data of what is currently going on and more static data that updated every few seconds (sessionInfo).

The first time a sessionInfo packet is received I need to position and size some of the UI elements according to some of the data in it. This data will definitely not change during the course of the application being used, so I do not want the calculations based on it to be executed more than once*.
I need to listen for all sessionInfo packets, there are other things I do with them when received, it is just this specific part of the data that only needs to be considered once.

**Given the above, is this a scenario where it would be appropriate to use a global variable to store this information (or even just a flag to say that this info had been processed) and use this to prevent the code executing multiple times?** All my reading suggests that Global Variables are never a good idea, but short of allowing this code to execute repeatedly I am unsure what alternatives I have here.

**I recognise that allowing this would probably make no practical difference to my application, but this is a learning experience for me as well as producing something useful so I would like to understand the 'right' approach rather than just bodge something inefficient together and make it work.*

Comment: There is barely any situation where a global variable is the best option, and never a situation where a global variable for a flag is the best option.

Comment: Since what you're trying to check on is the state of the UI, perhaps you should just check the state of the UI and see if it's already been positioned or not?  That state is globally available, but you don't have to introduce a global variable into your node.js code to do it.  You can either check the position of some element or you can check an attribute on some known UI element to see if the work has already been done or not.  As always, we could advise in more detail if you showed the actual code involved.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are generally a bad practice for many reasons like:

- They pollute the global scope, so if you create a global `i`, you
  can't use that name anywhere else.
- They make it impossible or very difficult to unit test your code.
- You usually end up needing more of them than you think, to the point where many things become global.

A better practice is to create singleton services. For example, you might create a SessionService class that handles all your auth stuff. Or, perhaps a DataStreamService that holds the state variables of your data stream. To access that singleton, you'd import it into whatever file needs it. Some frameworks go even farther and have a single global data store, like react/redux.